# FLASH MEDIA SERVER Cant connect to server from another pc in local network

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I got flash media server and I have a problem.
Client side is flash (AS3)
Server side is Action Script Server side (ASC)

I'm using RTMP protocol and 1935 port.
like so: rtmp://192.168.2.145:1935/simpleapp

I'm using NetConnection class to handle server-client events

I wanted to a chat app on local computers. In my PC, v'm opening a lot of clients for connecting to server and everything is working fine. I connected and I chatted with my other clients on my PC. However, if I open a client to connect fms from another PC in a local network, I couldn't connect to the server. And my client Netconnection catching this event

```
"NetConnection.Connect.Failed"
```

How to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be your router blocking traffic.
Are you sure the ports are open on your router?

Comment: i didnt notice. Maybe because of it. I'll check router ports. I'll share the result.

Comment: All ports (1935,80,1111) is opened permitted by router but problem didnt solve.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to try and see what is going on at the network level.

Comment: i didnt do this but i put my fms to online server. And it works with no problem, actually it was local network security issue.